# How to Properly Parse JSON with RegEx and '\' character?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Given the following code:

```
var a = 'somegarbage=http://somesite.com/foo/bar/&moregarbage';
var result = a.match(/http.+\//g);
```

Produces the expected result: `["http://somesite.com/foo/bar/"]`

Now, if I do this:

```
var a = 'somegarbage=http://somesite.com/foo/bar/&moregarbage';
var config = JSON.parse('{"filter":"/http.+\\//g"}'); //notice the extra '\'?
var result = a.match(config.filter);
```

It returns null. I presume that it has to do with the string escaping of `\` in JSON. I feel like I'm missing a simple solution. How can I fix this? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have also tried this and it doesn't work:

```
var a = 'somegarbage=http://somesite.com/foo/bar/&moregarbage';
var config = JSON.parse('{"filter":"/http.+\\//g"}'); //notice the extra '\'?
var result = a.match(new RegExp(config.filter));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't accept regular expressions as a type.  So, you need to just put the regular expression in a string (with the leading / and trailing / and then after you parse it, you need to feed the regular expression to new RegExp(str) to turn it into a regular expresssion.

You can do it like this:

```
var a = 'somegarbage=http://somesite.com/foo/bar/&moregarbage';
var x = JSON.parse('{"filter":"http.+/", "flags": "g"}');
x.filter = new RegExp(x.filter, x.flags);
var result = a.match(x.filter);
alert(result);​
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5pa2j/

Comment: You can see in my example code that it is a string, so I don't quite follow?

Comment: Yes, it's a string, NOT a regular expression and `JSON.parse()` doesn't turn your string into a regular expression.  Thus, when you pass `"/http.+\\//g"` to match, it tries to turn that into a regular expression and that doesn't match anything in your string.  See the code I added to my answer for one way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, the `/.../` syntax for RegExp is a special syntax, not just a string. If you want to to store your regex as a string in JSON, you need to use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
var config = JSON.parse('{"filter":"/http.+\\//g"}');
var result = a.match(new RegExp(config.filter));
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use RegExp

```
var a = 'somegarbage=http://somesite.com/foo/bar/&moregarbage';
var config = JSON.parse('{"filter":"http.+/"}'); 
var result = a.match(new RegExp(config.filter, "g"));
```